# how to create a QR code reader in android? (please explore step by step)

Tags: android

Hello friend i want to develop a QR code reader application for android and it's a first time for me so i have no idea that where is the starting point for develop a QR Code reader.
so please anyone explore the way of develop (Step by Step guidance). help me out please.....

Answer (score 10):

Here you go:

`Step 1. Read  http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html`

`Step 1a. Google for QR reader library for android`

`Step 2. Program App`

`Step 3. Post code you are having trouble with to StackOverflow`

`Step 4. Release app to market and make lots of money`

Shimples :)

Comment: great answer!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! i likeit

Comment: you forgot step 5.?????   step 6. get rich

Comment: step 1 and 1a are linked so no need for step 5 :)

Answer (score 5):

Have you check this library developped by Google : [Zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)? I have used for an Android Project and it's work very well.

Comment: This is a great opensource library and the main developer is pretty active in helping people figure out there problems.